# home directory . is reset to 777

Tags: permission, ssh

I'm trying to keep ssh access working without a password, using key authentication. I spent a lot of time looking for solutions until I stumbled across the need to set the home directory . to 711 (and found that 755 also works) but that 777 will not allow key authentication. I set my home directory . to 755 and it works as expected. However, after about 24 hours I'd say, the permission gets set back to 777 and I can't figure out why this is happening. Is this an expected behaviour? What is setting these permissions back to 777?

Comment: Permissions on $HOME/.ssh are what should matter, not $HOME.  Are you running Sophos Anti-Virus?

Comment: @MarcWilson Most likely both matter. With $HOME set to 777 I can easily change your existing .ssh to something of my liking.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? If you have several user accounts on your Mac (create a temporary one if not), does it only happen to your main user or to all of them?

Comment: $HOME permissions most definitely matter, it's a know "issue" that 777 on $HOME will not allow ssh key authentication. Not running any anti virus. This happens on several different machines with different mac OS versions